# Создать и заполнить документ данными из массива

Tags: 1с

В массиве лежит строка из БД MSSQL. Данными из нее я пытаюсь заполнить новый документ.

```
Для Каждого ЭлементМассива из Массив Цикл        
        Если ЭлементМассива.Id1C = "0" Тогда
            ДокументОбъект = Документы.Док1.СоздатьДокумент();
            ДокументОбъект.TEST = ЭлементМассива.TestName;             
            ДокументОбъект.Дата = ТекущаяДата();
            ДокументОбъект.Записать();              
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЦикла;
```

Проблема в том что, значение из "TestName" не попадает в реквизит "TEST". Тип у реквизита "TEST" содержит ссылку на справочник, и я так понимаю проблема именно в этом.

```
ДокументОбъект.TEST = ЭлементМассива.TestName;
```

Скажите что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `ЭлементМассива.TestName` — наименование, тогда:
`Справочники.TEST.НайтиПоНаименованию(ЭлементМассива.TestName)` вернёт ссылку на элемент справочника.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри тип `ЭлементМассива.TestName`. Если это и вправду тип строка - то ищи по наименованию ссылку. Только лучше `Справочники.TEST.НайтиПоНаименованию(ЭлементМассива.TestName, Истина)` - булево нужно, чтобы найти ТОЧНОЕ наименование, ибо он ищет чуть ли не первое попавшееся